# Firebase Hosting - Analytics

Tags: firebase

I deployed an website using Firebase Hosting. could i Know the website traffic? I know that I can see the downloads of the website but I wanna see a number of people or something like that.

Comment: So you need to read about firebase analytics/google analytics.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main ways to do this:

1. Implement [Google Analytics](https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/) (or even [Google Analytics for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/products/analytics?gclid=CjwKCAiAksyNBhAPEiwAlDBeLDPZyTTN83PrBFfTna3mGUivj1NAgodhxqOzz2YAQcPWoHKO4y0jjBoCHnQQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) if you are building more of an interactive app).
2. Enable [Cloud Logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/web-request-logs-and-metrics) which will cause a log entry to be generated for every request to Firebase Hosting, which you can then analyze using Cloud Monitoring, BigQuery, etc.

Based on your description (1) is probably the way to go as it's easy to implement and provides nice dashboards out-of-the-box.